# angular.forEach() inside $scope.$watch behaves weird - spits out duplicates

Tags: angularjs, foreach, apply, watch, digest

I am setting a $scope.$watch over an array with nested items with the following code:

```
$scope.$watch("networks",
                    function( newValue, oldValue ) {
                      if(JSON.stringify(oldValue)===JSON.stringify(newValue)){
                        return false;
                      }
                      else if(!(angular.isUndefinedOrNull(newValue) || angular.isUndefinedOrNull(oldValue))){
                        var oldValueCount = 0;
                      var validIndexArray=[];
                      var newValueCount = 0;
                      angular.forEach(newValue, function(item,i){
                        if(item.isSelected=='false'){
                          newValueCount++;
                          validIndexArray.push(i);
                        }
                      });
                      angular.forEach(oldValue, function(item,i){
                        if(item.isSelected=='false'){
                          oldValueCount++;
                        }
                      });
                      console.log("oldValueCount is"+oldValueCount);
                      $scope.netObject = {"keyid": "","value": "","actual":""};
                      if(oldValueCount==newValueCount===0){return false;}
                        if($rootScope.planBody.length!==0){
                          $rootScope.planBody.campaign.networks = [];
                        }
                        angular.forEach(validIndexArray, function(item,i){
                          $scope.netObject.keyid=newValue[item].keyid;
                          $scope.netObject.value=newValue[item].value;
                          $scope.netObject.actual=newValue[item].actual;
                          $rootScope.planBody.campaign.networks.push($scope.netObject);
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    true
                  );
```

The $rootScope.planBody.campaign.networks is getting populated with duplicates of the last element I update on the view. If I select 4 items, the 4th item repeats 4 times.

When I debugged and stepped into the final function,

```
angular.forEach(validIndexArray, function(item,i){...});
```

I found something weird - after one iteration, AFTER I've pushed one $scope.netObject into $rootScope.planBody.campaign.networks, when I re-enter the loop, at the first line:

```
$scope.netObject.keyid=newValue[item].keyid;
```

The pushed item ALREADY PUSHED INSIDE $rootScope.planBody.campaign.networks gets updated with the new value. This is causing the duplication.

1. Is something wrong with my code that is causing $digest to not apply? Should I be using an $apply?
2. If so is that the ideal solution?
3. If else, is there a better way of implementing my logic in angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the properties of an existing (and already pushed into the array) object.
You need to create a new empty object in each iteration:

```
angular.forEach(validIndexArray, function(item,i){
    $scope.netObject = {};
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you! The silliest of mistakes! I've changed the initialization and it works now